# Can not drag AxismarkerAnnotation in VerticallyStackedAxes correctly

Tags: scichart

I use VerticallStackedAxes of SciChart component and add 7 AxisMarkerAnnotation to each NumericAxis but AxisMarkerAnnotations not draggable except first of them.

[image: this is result:]

this is the part of my UserControl code:

```
<s:SciChartSurface.YAxes>
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch0" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch0" AxisTitle="Ch0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch1" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch1" AxisTitle="Ch1" Grid.Row="2" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch2" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch2" AxisTitle="Ch2" Grid.Row="4" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch3" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch3" AxisTitle="Ch3" Grid.Row="6" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch4" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch4" AxisTitle="Ch4" Grid.Row="8" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch5" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch5" AxisTitle="Ch5" Grid.Row="10" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch6" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch6" AxisTitle="Ch6" Grid.Row="12" />
                <s:NumericAxis x:Name="Ch7" Style="{StaticResource YAxisStyle}" Id="Ch7" AxisTitle="Ch7" Grid.Row="14" />
            </s:SciChartSurface.YAxes>

            <s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
                <s:ModifierGroup>
                    <s:RubberBandXyZoomModifier IsXAxisOnly="True"/>
                    <s:ZoomExtentsModifier/>
                    <s:CursorModifier ShowAxisLabels="False" ShowTooltip="False"/>
                </s:ModifierGroup>
            </s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>

            <s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>

                <!-- Draws Bands behind each axis -->
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch0" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch0}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch0}" Background="#11000000" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch1" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch1}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch1}" Background="#44B0C4DE" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch2" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch2}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch2}" Background="#11000000" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch3" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch3}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch3}" Background="#44B0C4DE" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch4" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch4}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch4}" Background="#11000000" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch5" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch5}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch5}" Background="#44B0C4DE" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch6" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch6}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch6}" Background="#11000000" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>
                <s:BoxAnnotation YAxisId="Ch7" CoordinateMode="RelativeX" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="{Binding VisibleRange.Min, ElementName=Ch7}" Y2="{Binding VisibleRange.Max, ElementName=Ch7}" Background="#44B0C4DE" AnnotationCanvas="BelowChart"/>

                <s:AxisMarkerAnnotation X1="0.0" 
                                        Y1="0.0"
                                        YAxisId="Ch0"
                                        IsEditable="True"
                                        LabelTemplate="{StaticResource AxisMarkerTemplate}"
                                        PointerTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultAxisPointerTemplate}"/>

                <s:AxisMarkerAnnotation X1="0.0" 
                                        Y1="0.0"
                                        YAxisId="Ch1"
                                        IsEditable="True"
                                        LabelTemplate="{StaticResource AxisMarkerTemplate}"
                                        PointerTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultAxisPointerTemplate}"/>
            </s:SciChartSurface.Annotations>
```

You can find source code in this url:
https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.WPF.Examples/tree/master/v4.x/Examples/SciChart.Examples/Examples/ModifyAxisBehaviour
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a bug in GetDataValue from axis class, that doesn't calculate yaxis offset.
In one of my projects, I fixed the problem with this class:

```
class FixedAxisMarkerAnnotation : AxisMarkerAnnotation
{
    protected override IComparable FromCoordinate(double coord, IAxis axis)
    {
        var coordinateCalculator = this.YAxis.GetCurrentCoordinateCalculator();

        if (!axis.IsXAxis)
            coord += coordinateCalculator.CoordinatesOffset;
        //

        return base.FromCoordinate(coord, axis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this problem, and currently investigating it.
Also you can track the progress on the issue here ===>>> https://abtsoftware.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/SC-4202

Nazar Pelyushkevych,
SciChart WPF team